# How to detect first and second-to-last p tags in a html string

Tags: java, android, html

I fetch a html string from the web and I format it using Html.fromHtml. Now I want to check for the first </p> tag and the </p> before the last one.

What I really wanted to do was to insert my own widget (e.g an ImageView) after these </p>

Please do you know how I could do that?

### Example of the Html

```
<h4>Headinf heading</h4>
<p>An an valley indeed so no wonder future nature vanity. Debating all she mistaken indulged believed provided declared. Hcted expression favourable any. Unknown chiefly showing to conduct no. Hung as love evil able to post at as.</p>
<p>Indulgence announcing <strong>uncommonly met she continuing two</strong> unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down the shed eyes roof paid her. Of shameless collected suspicion existence in. Share walls stuff think but the arise guest. Course suffer to do he sussex .</p>
<img src="http://example.com/imahe.png"/>
<p>AWhether at dearest certain spirits is entered in to. Rich fine bred real use too many good. She compliment unaffected expression favourable any. Unknown chiefly showing to conduct no. Hung as love evil able to post at as.</p>
<blockquote>Indulgence announcing <strong>uncommonly met she continuing two</strong> matter enable misery end extent common men should. Her indulgence but assistance favourable cultivated everything collecting.</blockquote>
<img src="http://example.com/imahe.png"/>
<p>Indulgence announcing <strong>uncommonly met she continuing two</strong>  end extent common men should. Her indulgence but assistance favourable cultivated everything collecting.</p>
<p>An an valley indeed so no wonder future nature vanity.  Unknown chiefly showing to conduct no. Hung as love evil able to post at as.</p>
```

Comment: you question is unclear. What you mean by **I want to check for the first </p> tag and the </p> before the last one.** ?? please elaborate..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya what I mean is that if I have say 10 closing l tags, I want check for the 1st and 19th tag and inflate a view after each one. Do you understand how?

Comment: You need to design some logic for that.. regarding to find `<p>` tags, Pair them, identify first n 2nd last and do something you want..!! Try something we'll help you if you face any problem..!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for "the first `</p>` tag and the `</p>` before the last one", maybe you could insert your own div after each of these closing paragraph tags, and assign them to the same class? Then you can reference those classes and insert your widget within those divs.

Comment: So how can I do that?